# Coletar dados da View para a controler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Gostaria de saber como posso coletar um dado da View, sendo que já estou utilizando o @model System.data.dataset.

```
@model System.Data.DataSet
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "CadastroPorto";
}
```

Preciso coletar os dados a qual será digitado nessa parte abaixo quando clicado no botão:

```
<section class="content-header">
   <div class="breadcrumb">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar novo Porto</button>
</div>
<div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome do Porto</label>
        </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Você pretende pegar os dado sem ter um formulário? seu código é só isto mesmo? como você pretende pegar na controller estes dados?

Comment: [Porque evitar datatable e dataset](http://thiagolunardi.net/2015/03/porque-evitar-datatable-e-dataset/)

Comment: @Thiago.Araujo Não é necessário formulário para se trafegar dados. Um bom exemplo é se tiver usando jQuery Ajax ou Angular.

Comment: De fato @ThiagoLunardi, minha intenção foi entender se ele estava usando somente as funcionalidades do c#, neste caso, se usaria BeginForm.

Comment: Se você pretende usar o ASP.NET Razor vai precisar de um formulário. Caso contrário, pode fazer como sugeriu o colega Thiago Lunardi e usar jQuery ou Angular.

Comment: Boa noite, No caso como pegar os dados seria indiferente por isso não coloquei o formulário. Para resolução utilizei o BeginForm passado por parâmetro os conteúdo do input. Agradeço a todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem bastante coisa estranha no código que mostrou. Uma `View` tipada deve ser do tipo de uma entidade sua. No seu exemplo, ela deve seria ser do tipo `Porto`.

```
@model `Porto`    
<label>Nome do Porto:</label> @Html.InputFor(porto => porto.NomeDoPorto);
```

E na `controller` que irá receber o novo porto:

```
[POST][Route("/api/porto")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddPorto (Porto porto)
{
    dbContext.Portos.Add(porto);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Utilizei o BeginForm. Porem vou fazer um exemplo dessa forma como fim didático. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Legal @AlexsandroTeixeira. Se realmente ajudar, não esqueça de marcar a resposta como ideal. Obrigado.